# Adding HID input state to SwitfUI environment

Tags: macos, swiftui

I've got a super-basic Swift class `MultiAxisDevice` that wraps the HID Manager and handles input from a 6-DOF space mouse. I would like to add it to my macOS app-wide environment so that any view can get updates of the device state. But I'm not sure where to instantiate it and set it up, and how to get at it in some arbitrary view.

Here's the wrapper:

```swift
class
MultiAxisDevice : ObservableObject
{
    init()
    {
        self.hidManager = HIDManager.shared
        self.hidManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    let         hidManager          :   HIDManager
    @Published var          state                                   =   MultiAxisState()
}


extension
MultiAxisDevice : HIDManagerDelegate
{
    func
    deviceValueReceived(device inDevice: HIDDevice, element inElement: IOHIDElement, cookie inCookie: IOHIDElementCookie, code inCode: Int)
    {
        //  SpaceMouse cookie 54 is roll axis
        
        var state = self.state
        
        switch (inCookie)
        {
            case 54:        state.roll = inCode
            default:
                break
        }
        
        self.state = state
    }
    
}

struct
MultiAxisState
{
    var         roll        :   Int     =   0
}
```

How can I make my SwiftUI views depend on that `MultiAxisState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the idiomatic way in SwiftUI 2.0 is to instantiate the model as a `@StateObject` towards the top of the application's view hierarchy and to then add it to the environment for descendant view to consume, e.g.

```
struct someParent: View {
    @StateObject private var model = MyTypeFoo()

    var body: some View {
            anotherView().environmentObject(model)
    }
}
```

The model can then be accessed in any direct descendant view of the parent as an `@EnvironmentObject` as follows

```
struct someDescendantOfAnotherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyTypeFoo 

    var body: some View {
       ... do something with model
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so I think this is one case where the normal SwiftUI update process doesn't work. I've got a SceneView, I and just want to update the SCNScene's camera position/attitude. This is a case where you don't want to reconstruct the view. So I really do need something like the `.onReceive()` closure.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out! I was lacking a `$` in my onReceive call. It should have been `.onReceive(self.multiAxisInput.$state)`. Once I fixe that, your help with getting it into the environment solved the problems.

Now if I could just determine if any given instance of my view is the one that should be manipulated with this (ie is the window frontmost?).

Comment: Hmm, probably missing something - but if nothing more direct turns up while Googling isn't the window at the front always going to be the last one that had focus? If that sounds promissing then Swiftui lab has a nice litte article on it over here https://swiftui-lab.com/working-with-focus-on-swiftui-views/ - Good luck.